# Posterior with a Beta prior and a liner function of Bernoulli data.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian, bayes-theorem

Let $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be fixed, known constants that satisfy$|a|+|b|<0.5$.$^1$ Let $\theta$ have a $\text{Beta}(\alpha,\beta)$ prior. Given an observation of $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(a+b\theta)$, what is the posterior distribution of $\theta$?

I am having trouble calculating this. Is it still $\text{Beta}(\cdot,\cdot)$?

---

$^1\ $ This just ensures that $X$'s distribution is well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posterior density is proportional to

$$\begin{align}
f(\theta \mid x) &\propto f_X(x \mid \theta, a, b) p(\theta) \\
&\propto (a + b\theta)^x (1 - (a + b\theta))^{1-x} \theta^{\alpha - 1} (1 - \theta)^{\beta - 1} \\
&= \begin{cases} (a + b \theta)\theta^{\alpha - 1} (1 - \theta)^{\beta - 1},  & x = 1 \\
(1 - a - b\theta)\theta^{\alpha - 1} (1 - \theta)^{\beta - 1}, & x = 0,\end{cases}
\end{align}$$  So no, it is not in general beta distributed because this cannot be written in the form $\theta^{\alpha^* - 1} (1 - \theta)^{\beta^* - 1}$ for suitable posterior hyperparameters $\alpha^*, \beta^*$ that are functions of $x, a, b$.

---

Regarding your follow-up question, the obvious choice of prior would be a suitable location-scaled beta, where the location parameter is $a$ and the scale is $b$:

$$p(\theta \mid a, b) = b \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha)\Gamma(\beta)} (a + b \theta)^{\alpha-1} (1 - (a+b \theta))^{\beta - 1}, \quad -\frac{a}{b} < \theta < \frac{1-a}{b},$$ since $a, b$ are known.  Then the posterior for a sample of size $n$ will be proportional to

$$f(\theta \mid x, a, b) \propto (a + b\theta)^{x+\alpha-1} (1 - (a + b\theta))^{n-x+\beta-1},$$ with the support of $\theta$ remaining the same.  Thus this prior is conjugate and the posterior hyperparameters are $$\alpha^* = x+\alpha, \quad \beta^* = n-x+\beta.$$

Basically, what we are doing is Bayesian inference on the transformed parameter $$\psi = a + b \theta,$$ with the usual binomial-beta model.  Then any properties of $\psi$ (e.g., posterior distribution, credible interval, highest posterior density interval) are simply back-transformed to obtain the corresponding inference on $\theta$.

There is one caveat:  if we know in advance the parameter $\theta \in (0,1)$, then this choice of prior will not work, because we are restricted on some subinterval depending on the values of $a$ and $b$:  specifically,
$$L = \max(0, -a/b) < \theta < \min(1, (1-a)/b) = U.$$
In this case, the posterior hyperparameters still obey the above relationship, but the distribution for $\theta$ is what might be called a "location-scale transformed, $(0,1)$-truncated" beta.  The normalizing constant becomes complicated, since a factor of $$\int_{\theta = L}^U p(\theta \mid a, b) \, d\theta$$ needs to be introduced.

---

Let's look at a specific example.  Suppose we have $a = -1/4$, and $b = 1/5$.  Then the observations $X_i$ will be Bernoulli with success parameter $\psi = -1/4 + \theta/5$ for some random variable $\theta$.  If there are no additional restrictions on $\theta$, then the requirement $0 < \psi < 1$ means we would have $5/4 < \theta < 25/4$, and we may proceed with inference using the transformed prior $\psi$, then back-transforming to get $\theta$.  Specifically, a uniform prior ($\alpha = \beta = 1$) would be $$p(\psi \mid a = -1/4, b = 1/5) = \begin{cases}1, & 0 < \psi < 1, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}$$ which if written for $\theta$ would be $$p(\theta \mid a = -1/4, b = 1/5) = \begin{cases}1/5, & 5/4 < \theta < 25/4, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  And a Beta prior with $\alpha = 2$, $\beta = 1$ would give us $$p(\psi \mid a = -1/4, b = 1/5) = \begin{cases} 2\psi, & 0 < \psi < 1, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ and $$p(\theta \mid a = -1/4, b = 1/5) = \begin{cases} 2\theta/5, & 5/4 < \theta < 25/4 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

But notice that if we imposed an additional condition that $0 < \theta < 1$, then $\psi$ will not be in $(0,1)$.

So now consider a second example:  $a = 1/4$, and $b = 1/3$.  In this case, the requirement $0 < \psi < 1$ implies $-3/4 < \theta < 9/4$, which has nonempty intersection with $(0,1)$.  So if $0 < \theta < 1$ is an added constraint, this would mean $1/4 < \psi < 7/12$, so a uniform prior for $\psi$ would need to be $$p(\psi \mid a = 1/4, b = 1/3) = \begin{cases} 3, & 1/4 < \psi < 7/12, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  The fact that the support for $\psi$ is not $(0,1)$ is due to the constraint on $\theta$--we had to truncate it.  Then in terms of $\theta$, we would have the uniform prior $$p(\theta \mid a = 1/4, b = 1/3) = \begin{cases} 1, & 0 < \theta < 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}; \end{cases}$$ namely, $\theta$ has full support on $(0,1)$ because we truncated both ends of $\psi$.  But the picture is a bit more complicated when the prior is not uniform; e.g., in the $\alpha = 2$, $\beta = 1$ case, the prior for $\psi$ is
$$p(\psi \mid a = 1/4, b = 1/3) = \begin{cases} \frac{36}{5} \psi, & 1/4 < \psi < 7/12, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}, \end{cases}$$ where $36/5$ comes from dividing the Beta $(\alpha = 2, \beta = 1)$ distribution on $0 < \psi < 1$ by the probability of the interval we are keeping, which is the normalizing factor $$\int_{\psi = 1/4}^{7/12} 2\psi \, d\psi = \frac{5}{18}.$$  Then back-transforming for $\theta$ gives
$$p(\theta \mid a = 1/4, b = 1/3) = \begin{cases} (4\theta + 3)/5, & 0 < \theta < 1, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$

Comment: Thanks so much @heropup! Would you happen to know a "convenient" choice of prior for $\theta$ in this scenario? (I.e. under the assumption that "data" are given by $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(a+b\theta)$.)

Comment: And "convenience" is of course subjective. If it seems convenient to you, that is good enough for me! 

But to set ideas: roughly speaking, conjugate priors are "convenient" in that they guarantee "consistency" in the type of distribution one works with. If you know a suitable conjugate prior that applies here then great! Otherwise, a prior that is "convenient" in a different sense is fine :)

Thanks so much again!

Comment: @cluelessmathematician See edited response.

Comment: You're my hero @heropup  Seriously, this is so unbelievably helpful, and I deeply appreciate it.

Comment: just wanted to clarify: when you said "if we know in advance the parameter θ∈(0,1)," do you mean we know that θ is *some element* of (0,1)? (I assume you don't mean we observed the *value* of θ itself?)

Comment: @cluelessmathematician Yes.  Inference on $\theta$, if restricted to the interval $0 < \theta < 1$, would require us to choose a prior whose distribution has support on that interval.  To do this, we would have to modify the distribution of the transformed prior $\psi$ because if we let $0 < \psi < 1$, then the inverse transformation might give you an inference for $\theta$ that lies outside $0 < \theta < 1$.  The required modification would then be to truncate the tails depending on the values of $a$ and $b$.